# too much moves in armature - pose

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

in pose also the ribs move although I only move the arm
[image]

[image]

I have nothing parent
[image]

unfortunately I don't know how to get this fixed

My Blender file:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amok31-g9Vyoid1QzxhrViaikey4_A?e=DdsUhv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've parented the the ribs to the armature, so accidentally the arm acts on the ribs and you need to correct that:

- Select the arm to know its name:

[image]

- Select the ribs, go in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, find the vertex groups that has the same name, click on *Remove*:

[image]

The lower arm influences the ribs as well so do the same. You can also do it in *Weight Paint* mode.

Comment: Great thanks; thanks my problem is solved 100% with these easy illustrated steps